# Оптимизировать метод обсчета поля игры 2048

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Сижу ломаю голову, как избавиться от повторяющегося кода.

[2048](https://play2048.co/) игру же знаете, пишу свой вариант реализации. Есть массив тайлов, каждый тайл представляет из себя

```js
const cell = {
  row : 1,
  col : 1,
  value : 32,
  merged : false,
  node : <HTMLElement>
}
```

Логически имеется игровое поле 4x4 тайла.

**Задача:** при выполнении игроком хода нужно пройти по всему полю и двинуть тайлы в нужном направлении попутно смержив те, что имеют одинаковые значения.

Этот код работает, но выглядит ужасно. Он реализует только логику перемещения и мержа тайлов используя только массив тайлов. Технически DOM обновляется в другом методе, фактический мерж тайлов тоже происходит позднее, здесь ставится только метка на тайл, что он будет смержен. Удаляемому тайлу просто задается значение 0.

```js
const size = 4;

function move(direction) {
  let moved = false;
  if (direction === 'left') {
    for (let col = 1; col < size; col++) {
      for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        const cell = getCell(row, col);
        if (cell && !cell.merged) {
          let targetCol;
          for (targetCol = col - 1; targetCol >= 0; targetCol--) {
            const targetCell = getCell(row, targetCol);
            if (!targetCell)
              continue;
            if (targetCell.value == cell.value && !targetCell.merged) {
              cell.value = 0;
              targetCell.merged = true;
            }
            break;
          }
          if (cell.value != 0)
            targetCol++;
          if (col != targetCol) {
            moveCol(cell, targetCol);
            moved = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (direction === 'right') {
    for (let col = size - 2; col >= 0; col--) {
      for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        const cell = getCell(row, col);
        if (cell && !cell.merged) {
          let targetCol;
          for (targetCol = col + 1; targetCol < size; targetCol++) {
            const targetCell = getCell(row, targetCol);
            if (!targetCell)
              continue;
            if (targetCell.value == cell.value && !targetCell.merged) {
              cell.value = 0;
              targetCell.merged = true;
            }
            break;
          }
          if (cell.value != 0)
            targetCol--;
          if (col != targetCol) {
            moveCol(cell, targetCol);
            moved = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (direction === 'up') {
    for (let row = 1; row < size; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        const cell = getCell(row, col);
        if (cell && !cell.merged) {
          let targetRow;
          for (targetRow = row - 1; targetRow >= 0; targetRow--) {
            const targetCell = getCell(targetRow, col);
            if (!targetCell)
              continue;
            if (targetCell.value == cell.value && !targetCell.merged) {
              cell.value = 0;
              targetCell.merged = true;
            }
            break;
          }
          if (cell.value != 0)
            targetRow++;
          if (row != targetRow) {
            moveRow(cell, targetRow);
            moved = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (direction === 'down') {
    for (let row = size - 2; row >= 0; row--) {
      for (let col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        const cell = getCell(row, col);
        if (cell && !cell.merged) {
          let targetRow;
          for (targetRow = row + 1; targetRow < size; targetRow++) {
            const targetCell = getCell(targetRow, col);
            if (!targetCell)
              continue;
            if (targetCell.value == cell.value && !targetCell.merged) {
              cell.value = 0;
              targetCell.merged = true;
            }
            break;
          }
          if (cell.value != 0)
            targetRow--;
          if (row != targetRow) {
            moveRow(cell, targetRow);
            moved = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return moved;
}
```

В лоб способ оптимизации не могу найти. Возможно нужно менять алгоритм, помогите разобраться.

**Алгоритм**, например для движения влево (left):

- просматриваю строку по колонкам от 0, то есть слева направо
- если нахожу тайл, проверяю, есть ли тайл левее
- если есть, проверяю его значение
- если совпадает и тайл не был замержен ранее, то мержу
- двигаю тайл в соответствии с выше выполненным условием, то есть либо в мерж, либо в дальнюю свободную клетку слева, если она есть
- перехожу к следующей строке

Вызываемые методы из кода выше, для референса

```js
const cells = [];
const cellSize = 100 / size;

function moveRow(cell, row) {
  cell.row = row;
  cell.node.style.top = (row * cellSize) + '%';  
}

function moveCol(cell, col) {
  cell.col = col;
  cell.node.style.left = (col * cellSize) + '%';
}

function getCell(row, col) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    const cell = cells[i];
    if (cell.row == row && cell.col == col && cell.value != 0)
      return cell;
  }
}
```

Comment: добавь описание алгоритма.

Comment: @Grundy исправлено

Comment: _просматриваю строку по колонкам от 0 до 3_ - а всего сколько колонок?

Comment: @Grundy 4 :) исправлено

Comment: сейчас виден явный дубляж для лево/верх и низ/право

Comment: стоит все-таки механику игры тоже описать - сначала про другое управление думал, из-за этого и реализация движения может отличаться

Comment: @Grundy механика точь в точь как в оригинале, ссылка на оригинал выше, потыкать кнопки минуту и все понятно станет. Сложно описать это с нуля именно текстом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130049/discussion-between-grundy-and-aepot).

Comment: Я вот только одного не могу понять, если вы делаете такую же игру с теми же параметрами, то почему бы не взять алгоритм автора оригинала? зачем искать другой алгоритм? Чтобы код выглядел как академический, нужно усложнить код применением парадигм ООП. Возможно, на TypeScript  код выглядел бы чуток красивее.

Comment: @DiD я хорошо знаю шарп, но плохо JS, на уровне продвинутого чайника. А следовательно пока еще верю в магию экспертов, которые придут и что-нибудь интересное подскажут. Мне не нужно этот код сдавать преподу, я сам его пишу для своих целей, поэтому почти всё равно как он выглядит в целом, но мне он не нравится в текущем виде. Потому что DRY. Цель вопроса здесь - научиться чему-то новому, если повезёт, конечно.

Comment: *просматриваю строку по колонкам от 0, то есть слева направо* Почему не от 1? нулевой по дефолту не с чем мержить и некуда двигать - край доски. *если нахожу тайл, проверяю, есть ли тайл левее* На самом деле тебе надо обработать три взаимоисключающие ситуации. 1) IF слева пусто, действие `node(i-1)=node(i);node(i)=0;` 2) ELSEIF слева непусто, и `node(i-1)=node(i)`, действие `node(i-1)=2*node(i);node(i)=0;` 3) ELSE - ничего не делать, перейти к следующему node.

Comment: Кстати, для описанного выше алгоритма разумнее, если массив node будет одномерным, тогда обрабатываем node с 4 по 15, и сравниваем с node(i-4).

Comment: @Akina у меня немного по-другому, массив содержит только существующие тайлы. Пустых тайлов там нет вообще. Но я уже понял по нижеприведенным ответам, что это не очень удачное решение. Буду переделывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не заморачиваться с анимацией, то проще всего сделать через таблицы. Хранить длинные числа большого смысла тоже не имеет. Можно хранить только степени двоек.

```js
// Вообще, задача не требует ООП, но пусть будет класс игры
class Game {
  // Свойство содержит количество колонок
  colsNum;
  // Свойство содержит количество строк
  rowsNum;
  // Свойство содержит степени двоек всех ячеек
  raw;
  // Свойство содержит ссылку на таблицу <table>
  actor;
  // Конструктор
  constructor(props) {
    // Применить свойства к this
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
  // Метод генерирует таблицу
  init() {
    // Заполняем массив степеней двоек нолями
    this.raw = new Array(this.colsNum * this.rowsNum).fill(0);
    // На всякий отчистим таблицу
    this.actor.innerHTML = '';
    // Перебор строк
    // ri - индекс строки
    // rn - количество строк
    for (let ri = 0, rn = this.rowsNum; ri < rn; ri++) {
      // Создаем <tr>
      let tr = document.createElement('tr');
      // Перебор колонок
      // ci - индекс колонки
      // cn - количество колонок
      for (let ci = 0, cn = this.colsNum; ci < cn; ci++) {
        // Создаем <td> и помещаем в <tr>
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
      }
      // Помещаем <tr> в <table>
      this.actor.appendChild(tr);
    }
    // Добавляем две рандомные ячейки для начала игры
    this.addRand();
    this.addRand();
    return this;
  }
  // Метод добавляет рандомное число в рандомную свободную ячейку
  addRand() {
    // Массив свободных ячеек
    let free = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = this.raw.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (!this.raw[i]) {
        free.push(i);
      }
    }
    // Выбираем рандомную ячейку
    const cell = free[~~(Math.random() * free.length)];
    // Выбираем степень новой двойки 1 или 2
    const value = ~~(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    // Запишем ко всем остальным ячейкам
    this.raw[cell] = value;
    // Обновляем виды
    this.update();
  }
  // Свойство возвращает массив колонок
  get cols() {
    let cols = [];
    for (let ci = 0, cn = this.colsNum; ci < cn; ci++) {
      let col = [];
      for (let ri = 0, rn = this.rowsNum; ri < rn; ri++) {
        col.push(this.raw[ri * cn + ci]);
      }
      cols.push(col);
    }
    return cols;
  }
  // Свойство принимает массив колонок и записывает ко всем степеням двоек
  set cols(v) {
    for (let ci = 0, cn = this.colsNum; ci < cn; ci++) {
      for (let ri = 0, rn = this.rowsNum; ri < rn; ri++) {
        this.raw[ri * cn + ci] = v[ci][ri];
      }
    }
  }
  // Свойство возвращает массив строк
  get rows() {
    let rows = [];
    for (let ri = 0, rn = this.rowsNum; ri < rn; ri++) {
      let row = [];
      for (let ci = 0, cn = this.colsNum; ci < cn; ci++) {
        row.push(this.raw[ri * cn + ci]);
      }
      rows.push(row);
    }
    return rows;
  }
  // Свойство принимает массив строк и записывает ко всем степеням двоек
  set rows(v) {
    for (let ri = 0, rn = this.rowsNum; ri < rn; ri++) {
      for (let ci = 0, cn = this.colsNum; ci < cn; ci++) {
        this.raw[ri * cn + ci] = v[ri][ci];
      }
    }
  }
  // Метод управления игрой
  // dir - направление
  // u - вверх
  // d - вниз
  // l - влево
  // r - вправо
  swap(dir) {
    let property, method;
    // Можно было бы использовать карту наподобие keyMap как по коду внизу,
    // но для академичности можно воткнуть switch
    switch (dir) {
      case 'u':
        [property, method] = ['cols', 'reverse'];
        break;
      case 'd':
        [property, method] = ['cols', 'forward'];
        break;
      case 'r':
        [property, method] = ['rows', 'forward'];
        break;
      case 'l':
        [property, method] = ['rows', 'reverse'];
        break;
    }
    let lines = this[property];
    // Вызываем метод сдвига
    if (this.sum(lines.map(line => this[method](line)))) {
      // Если что-то сдвинулось, то записываем результат
      this[property] = lines;
      // Добавляем еще 2 или 4 в рандомную ячейку
      this.addRand();
    }
  }
  // Метод делает обновление видов
  update() {
    let tds = this.actor.querySelectorAll('td');
    for (let i = 0, l = this.raw.length; i < l; i++) {
      tds[i].innerHTML = this.raw[i] ? 2 ** this.raw[i] : '';
    }
  }
  // Метод считает сумму аргументов
  sum(...as) {
    return as.flat(Infinity).reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0);
  }
  // Метод сдвигает одну линию к началу
  // raw - одномерный массив степеней двоек
  reverse(raw) {
    // Количество сдвинутых ячеек
    let swapped = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < raw.length - 1;) {
      if (!raw[i] && this.sum(raw.slice(i + 1, raw.length))) {
        raw.splice(i, 1);
        swapped++;
      } else i++;
    }
    // Заполняем конец массива недостающими нулями
    raw.splice(raw.length, 0, ...new Array(swapped).fill(0));
    // Количество совмещенных ячеек
    let mixed = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < raw.length; i++) {
      if (raw[i - 1] && raw[i - 1] == raw[i]) {
        raw.splice(i - 1, 2, raw[i] + 1);
        mixed++;
      }
    }
    // Заполняем конец массива недостающими нулями
    raw.splice(raw.length, 0, ...new Array(mixed).fill(0));
    return swapped + mixed;
  }
  // Метод сдвигает одну линию к концу
  // raw - одномерный массив степеней двоек
  forward(raw) {
    // Количество сдвинутых ячеек
    let swapped = 0;
    for (let i = raw.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (!raw[i] && this.sum(raw.slice(0, i))) {
        raw.splice(i, 1);
        swapped++;
      }
    }
    // Заполняем начало массива недостающими нулями
    raw.splice(0, 0, ...new Array(swapped).fill(0));
    // Количество совмещенных ячеек
    let mixed = 0;
    for (let i = raw.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (raw[i] && raw[i] == raw[i + 1]) {
        raw.splice(i, 2, raw[i] + 1);
        mixed++;
        i--;
      }
    }
    // Заполняем начало массива недостающими нулями
    raw.splice(0, 0, ...new Array(mixed).fill(0));
    return swapped + mixed;
  }
}

// Инициализация игры
const game = new Game({
  // Ссылка на готовый элемент <table> уже присутствующий на странице
  actor: document.querySelector('table'),
  // Количество колонок
  colsNum: 4,
  // Количество строк
  rowsNum: 4,
}).init();

// Клавишная карта.
let keyMap = new Map([
  ['ArrowUp', 'u'],
  ['ArrowDown', 'd'],
  ['ArrowLeft', 'l'],
  ['ArrowRight', 'r'],
  ['KeyW', 'u'],
  ['KeyS', 'd'],
  ['KeyA', 'l'],
  ['KeyD', 'r'],
  ['KeyK', 'u'],
  ['KeyJ', 'd'],
  ['KeyH', 'l'],
  ['KeyL', 'r'],
]);
// Обработчик нажатий клавиш
window.onkeydown = e => {
  // Специально для SO, чтобы страница не дергалась если жать на стрелочки
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Код нажатой клавиши
  const {code} = e;
  // Если клавиша есть в списке
  if (keyMap.has(code)) {
    // То свопаем игру в правильном направлении
    game.swap(keyMap.get(code));
  }
};
```

```css
/* Это для сопроводительной надписи */
body { font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; } 
/* Выравнивание и небольшой отступ  */
table { float: left; margin-right: 4rem;}
/* Стили ячейки */
td {
  width: calc(25vmin - 10px);
  height: calc(25vmin - 10px);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(10vmin);
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif; }
/* Это для визуального выделения названий клавиш */
span { border: 1px solid #000; 
      display:inline-block; 
      height: 1rem; 
      width: 1rem; 
      line-height: 1rem; 
       text-align:center; padding: }
```

```html
<!-- Таблица уже присутствует на странице -->
<table></table>

Управлять игрой можно клавишами: 
<ul>
  <li><span>⬅</span> <span>⬇</span> <span>⬆</span> <span>⮕</span></li> 
  <li><span>W</span> <span>A</span> <span>S</span> <span>D</span></li>
  <li><span>H</span> <span>J</span> <span>K</span> <span>L</span></li>
</ul>.
```

Проверку на выигрыш или проигрыш не делал.

Чуть позже мне пришла идея, хранить состояние в одной строке,  (один символ - одна фишка), если кодировать в шестнадцатеричной системе. Или если делать большие поля (5х5 или 10х10), то большие числа также можно хранить вплоть до 36-ричной системы.

Переводы между строками и числами можно делать так:

```js
let num, str;

num = 30;

str = num.toString(36);
console.log(`str = ${JSON.stringify(str)};`);

num = parseInt(str, 36);
console.log(`num = ${JSON.stringify(num)};`);
```

Чуть позже напишу комментариев к коду. Но если будут вопросы - спрашивайте, отвечу как увижу.

Comment: Спасибо за решение, этот ответ содержит для меня много нового, но я освоил. От дублирования кода избавиться удалось, да и кода стало значительно меньше, очень полезный ответ.

Comment: Стоит посмотреть код из [другого моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1359395/406363)

Comment: я смотрел, спасибо, тоже полезно.

Answer (score 5):

```js
let cvalue = [[0,2,16,2],[0,0,8,0],[4,0,2,2],[4,8,16,0]];

let placeHolder = document.getElementById("main");

for(let i =0; i<16; i++){
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
  cell.className = "cell";
  cell.innerText = cvalue[(i-i%4)/4][i%4]||"";
  placeHolder.appendChild(cell); 
}

function update(){
    for(let i =0; i<16; i++){
        placeHolder.children[i].innerText = cvalue[(i-i%4)/4][i%4]||"";
    }
}

document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click",()=>{move({x:0,y:1})});
document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click",()=>{move({x:0,y:-1})});
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click",()=>{move({x:1,y:0})});
document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click",()=>{move({x:-1,y:0})});

function move(direction){
  //в зависимости от нажатой кнопки передаем направление движения 
  //по осям и какой ряд вертикально или горизонтально не важно их всегда 4
    for(let r=0; r<4; r++){ //r - порядковый номер рядя или столбца
        row(r,direction);
    }
  update(); // ну и обновим
}

function row(row, direction){
    let lastCell = 0; // тут будем хранить ячейку в которую что то положим
    let x,y;
  
  // пройдём по элементам ряда или столбца их у нас всегда четыре
    for( let pos = 0; pos < 4; pos++ ){
    if(direction.x == 0 ){
        // если направление по х нулевое значит перемещаемя горизонтально по ряду row 
        x = row;
        y = (direction.y>=0 ? direction.y*pos + 0 : direction.y*pos + 3);
      // позиция по y будет в зависимости от направления direction.y 
      // при положительном значении будет от 0 вверх,
      // а при отрицательном от 3 вниз
    }else{
        // если направление по y нулевое значит перемещаемя вертикально по столбцу row
        y = row; 
        x = (direction.x>=0 ? direction.x*pos : direction.x*pos + 3);
    }
    
    
    if(lastCell == 0){ 
      // если это первая ячейка в нашем ряду или столбце lastCell равно нулю 
      //пока мы не определили туда ничего
        lastCell = {row: x, col: y, val: cvalue[x][y]};
      continue; //переходим к следующей
    }
        if(cvalue[x][y] == 0) { //пустая пропустим
        continue;
    }else if(cvalue[x][y] == lastCell.val){
              //одинаковые значения перекидываем отсюда в lastCell
        cvalue[lastCell.row][lastCell.col] += cvalue[x][y];
        // эту обнуляем она стала пустая
        cvalue[x][y] = 0;
        //в lastCell уже ложить не может сдвинемся на следующую она пустая в любом случае
        lastCell.row += direction.x;
        lastCell.col += direction.y;
        lastCell.val = 0;
    }else{
        // нельзя мержить значит ложим в соседнюю с lastCell
        if(lastCell.val == 0){ //ячейка пуста просто переносим значение
                             //и lastCell остается мы же можем в нёё мержить ?
            cvalue[lastCell.row][lastCell.col] = cvalue[x][y];
              lastCell.val = cvalue[x][y];
              cvalue[x][y] = 0;
        }else{ // ячейка заполнена и не подходит нужно перейти к следубщей
            lastCell.row += direction.x;
            lastCell.col += direction.y;
            if(lastCell.row == x && lastCell.col == y ) {
                // это случай когда между ячейками нет свободных 
                // мы ничего не перемещаем и теперь в lastCell у нас значение ячейки X:Y
                  lastCell.val = cvalue[x][y];
                continue; //тогда просто идём дальше
            }
            cvalue[lastCell.row][lastCell.col] = cvalue[x][y];
            lastCell.val = cvalue[x][y];
            cvalue[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.buttons{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#main {
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
}
.cell{
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="left">LEFT</button>
  <button id="right">RIGHT</button>
  <button id="up">UP</button>
  <button id="down">DOWN</button>
</div>

<div id="main">
</div>
```

Comment: Выглядит как полностью альтернативное решение. Спасибо, буду разбираться. Пока только вижу странность `cvalue[lastCell.row][lastCell.col] += cvalue[x][y];` Мне всегда казалось, что `x` это колонка, а `y`- это строка. Здесь точно ничего не перепутано?

Comment: да так и есть точно, случайно так вышло что 'х' это ряд

Answer (score 2):

Можно поворачивать игровое поле так, чтобы сдвиг выполнялся всегда слева направо, затем сдвигать ячейки и поворачивать поле обратно.

```
//преобразовываем координаты чтобы сдвиг выполнялся слева направо
if (direction === 'left') {
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.oldRow = cell.row
        cell.oldCol = cell.col
        cell.col = size - 1 - cell.col
    })
}
if (direction === 'right') {
    //ничего
}
if (direction === 'up') {
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.oldRow = cell.row
        cell.oldCol = cell.col
        cell.col = cell.oldRow
        cell.row = size - 1 - cell.oldCol
    })
}
if (direction === 'down') {
    cells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.oldRow = cell.row
        cell.oldCol = cell.col
        cell.col = cell.oldRow
        cell.row = cell.oldCol
    })
}

//сдвигаем вправо
move('right') //Нужно почистить функцию и оставить только часть кода внутри direction === 'right'

//восстанавливаем координаты обратно
cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.row = cell.oldRow
    cell.col = cell.oldCol
})
```

Можно этот алгоритм преобразования координат перенести в функцию `getCell`:

```
function getCell(row, col, direction) {
    if (direction === 'left') {
        col = size - 1 - cell.col
    }
    if (direction === 'up') {
        let oldRow = row
        row = size - 1 - col
        col = oldRow
    }
    if (direction === 'down') {
        let oldRow = row
        row = col
        col = oldRow
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        const cell = cells[i];
        if (cell.row === row && cell.col === col && cell.value !== 0) {
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Несложно заметить, что при хранении элементов в плоском массиве разные варианты перебора столбцов и строк отличаются только стартовой позицией и смещениями при переходе к следующим элементам. Соответственно имеет смысл не хардкодить эти величины, а вынести их в отдельную С++style табличку и обращаться к ней при входе в функцию. Также для практической реализации, если надо делать анимации перескакивания и схлопывания ячеек, то имеет смыл добавить в функцию третий аргумент, принимающий функцию обратного вызова для соотв. оповещений.

```
type Field = Array<number>;

type Direction = 'left' | 'right' | 'up' | 'down';

type Navigation = { initial: number; next_col: number; next_row: number; };

type Lookup = { [direction in Direction]: Navigation; };

const dim = 4;

const cells_count = dim * dim;

const lookup: Lookup =
{
    left : { initial: 0              , next_col:  1  , next_row: dim }
,   right: { initial: (dim - 1)      , next_col: -1  , next_row: dim }
,   up   : { initial: 0              , next_col:  dim, next_row: 1   }
,   down : { initial: (dim - 1) * dim, next_col: -dim, next_row: 1   }
};

function Fold(input: Field, direction: Direction): Field
{
    const output = new Array<number>(cells_count).fill(0);
    const navigation = lookup[direction];
    let remaining = cells_count;
    let pos = navigation.initial;
    for (;;)
    {
        let read_pos = pos;
        let write_pos = pos;
        for (;;)
        {
            if (0 !== input[read_pos])
            {
                if (output[write_pos] !== input[read_pos])
                {
                    if (0 !== output[write_pos])
                    {
                        write_pos += navigation.next_col;
                    }
                    output[write_pos] = input[read_pos];
                }
                else
                {
                    output[write_pos] *= 2;
                    write_pos += navigation.next_col;
                }
            }
            --remaining;
            if (0 === (remaining % dim))
            {
                break; // inner loop
            }
            read_pos += navigation.next_col;
            continue; // inner loop
        }
        if (0 === remaining)
        {
            break; // outer loop
        }
        pos += navigation.next_row;
        continue; // outer loop
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. TS мне не катит, но идею понял.

Comment: @aepot ¿Почему не катит? А вообще он легким движением превращается в js.

Comment: Оно понятно, спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Решил немного расширить ответ. А новый код вместе со старым ответом в один ответ не вместился. Потому выложу отдельным ответом.

Прикрутил к демке выбор размера поля, две кнопки перехода по истории вперед-назад, индикатор набранных очков, обработчики touch-событий для управления с мобильных гаджетов и еще несколько неважных улучшений.

В целом, демка получилась неплохая. Над анимацией еще поработать надо.

Будут вопросы - задавайте. Код может работать некорректно. Если заметили баг, напишите, исправим.

```js
// Порог срабатывания приковнования
const TOUCH_THRESHOLD = 50;
// Цветовая схнма
COLOR_SCHEMA = [
  'E57373',
  'F06292',
  'BA68C8',
  '9575CD',
  '7986CB',
  '64B5F6',
  '4FC3F7',
  '4DD0E1',
  '4DB6AC',
  '81C784',
  'AED581',
  'DCE775',
  'FFF176',
  'FFD54F',
  'FFB74D',
  'FF8A65',
  'A1887F',
  '90A4AE',
  'E0E0E0',
];

// Математические функции и константа
const { abs, round, random, max, min, sin, cos, hypot, atan2, PI: π, E:  } = Math;
// Функции Object
const { assign, entries, fromEntries } = Object;
// Хэлпер querySelector
const sel = (...q) =>
  !q.length
? null
: Array.isArray(q[0])
? sel(q[0].reduce((r, s, i) => ((r += (i ? q[i] : '') + s), r), ''))
: q.reduce((r, s) => (!r ? null : 'object' == typeof s ? s : r.querySelector(s)), document);
// Хэлпер querySelectorAll
const selAll = (...q) =>
  !q.length
? null
: Array.isArray(q[0])
? selAll(q[0].reduce((r, s, i) => ((r += (i ? q[i] : '') + s), r), ''))
: q.reduce(
(r, s, i, q) =>
  !r ? null : 'object' == typeof s ? s : r['querySelector' + (i == q.length - 1 ? 'All' : '')](s),
document
  );
// Хэлперы классов
const addCls = (el, ...cls) => (el.classList.add(...cls), el);
const remCls = (el, ...cls) => (el.classList.remove(...cls), el);
// Хэлпер аттрибутов
const attr = (el, atr, val) => (typeof val == 'undefined' ? el.getAttribute(atr) : (el.setAttribute(atr, val), el));
// Хэлпер createElement
const create = def => {
  const el = document.createElement(def.tag || 'div');
  if (def.cls) el.className = def.cls;
  if (def.css) assign(el.style, def.css);
  if (def.evt) entries(def.evt).forEach(([evt, cb]) => el.addEventListener(evt, cb, false));
  if (def.tgt) def.tgt.appendChild(el);
  if (def.atr) entries(def.atr).forEach(([atr, val]) => attr(el, atr, val));
  if (def.txt) el.innerHTML = def.txt;
  if (def.chd) {
if (Array.isArray(def.chd)) def.chd.forEach(subdef => create({ tgt: el, ...subdef }));
else create({ tgt: el, ...def.chd });
  }
  return el;
};
// Останавливает событие
const stop = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
};
// Преобразователь массива в строку
const arr2str = arr => arr.map(val => (+val).toString(36)).join``;
// Преобразователь строки в массив
const str2arr = str => [...str].map(chr => parseInt(chr, 36));
// Схемы клавиатуры
[
  ['left', 'down', 'up', 'right', 'undo', 'redo'],
  ['⬅', '⬇', '⬆', '⮕', '⌫', '⏎'],
  ['H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'U', '.'],
  ['A', 'S', 'W', 'D', 'Z', 'R'],
].forEach((scheme, idx) =>
  create({
tag: 'tr',
chd: scheme.map(key => ({ tag: idx ? 'td' : 'th', chd: { tag: 'span', cls: 'key', txt: key } })),
tgt: sel('table'),
  })
);
//Уровни сложности
[
  [3, 8],
  [4, 11],
  [5, 14],
  [6, 16],
  [7, 19],
].forEach(([size, adv]) =>
  create({
tag: 'button',
atr: { size, adv },
chd: [
  { tag: 'label', cls: 'size', txt: `<b>${size}</b>&times;<b>${size}</b>` },
  { tag: 'hr' },
  { tag: 'label', cls: 'advance', txt: `to <b>${adv}</b>` },
],
evt: {
  click: evt => {
let target = evt.target.closest('button');
createGame({ size: +attr(target, 'size'), adv: +attr(target, 'adv') });
  },
},
tgt: sel('.new-game'),
  })
);
// Стили для фрейма выигрыша
create({
  tag: 'style',
  txt: `.frame.success h3, .frame.success .score { animation: css-fizzy 12s linear 0s infinite; }
@keyframes css-fizzy{
  ${new Array(13)
.fill(0)
.map(
  (v, frameIdx) =>
`${(100 / 12) * frameIdx}% {text-shadow: ${[
  '0 0 0.2em',
  '0 0 0.2em',
  ...new Array(8)
.fill(0)
.map(
  (v, shdowPartIdx) =>
    `${(-1.6) ** shdowPartIdx * sin((frameIdx / 6) * π)}px ${
      (-1.6) ** shdowPartIdx * cos((frameIdx / 6) * π)
    }px ${1.6 ** shdowPartIdx + 0.2}px`
),
]
  .map((shadow, shadowIdx) => `${shadow} hsl(${frameIdx * 30}deg,99%,${70 - 5 * shadowIdx}%)`)
  .join()};}`
).join``}
}`,
  tgt: document.body,
});
// текущая игра
var game;
// текущее косание
let cur = { pageX: null, pageY: null };
// Обработчик кнопок закрытия
selAll('button.exit').forEach(
  btn =>
(btn.onclick = e =>
  attr(e.target.closest('.frame'), 'mode') == 'export' ? (setFrame('game'), activateListeners()) : closeGame())
);
// Обработчик кнопкт Экспорт
sel('button.export').onclick = e => {
  deactivateListeners();
  const txtAr = sel('textarea');
  txtAr.value = JSON.stringify(game.serialize());
  attr(setFrame('memo'), 'mode', 'export');
  txtAr.select();
};
// Обработчик кнопки import
sel('button.import').onclick = e => {
  deactivateListeners();
  const txtAr = sel('textarea');
  txtAr.value = '';
  attr(setFrame('memo'), 'mode', 'import');
  txtAr.select();
};
// Обработчик кнопки OK
sel('button.ok').onclick = e => {
  const txtAr = sel('textarea');
  if (attr(txtAr.closest('.frame'), 'mode') == 'import') {
try {
  let obj = JSON.parse(txtAr.value);
  // TODO: Check JSON-data
  createGame(obj);
} catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
  } else {
setFrame('game');
activateListeners();
  }
};
// Обработчик кнопки Undo
sel('button.undo').onclick = e => {
  game.undo();
};
// Обработчик кнопки Redo
sel('button.redo').onclick = e => {
  game.redo();
};
// отчищает текущее косание
function clearCur() {
  cur.pageX = cur.pageY = null;
}
// устанавливает начало текущего косания
function setCur(touch) {
  cur.pageX = touch.pageX;
  cur.pageY = touch.pageY;
}
// определяет направление косания
function dirCur(touch) {
  const dX = touch.pageX - cur.pageX;
  const dY = touch.pageY - cur.pageY;
  const d = Math.hypot(dX, dY);
  if (d > TOUCH_THRESHOLD && (abs(dY) > 2 * abs(dX) || 2 * abs(dY) < abs(dX))) {
let side = ((π + atan2(dX, dY)) / π) * 2;
side = round(side);
side = side < 4 ? side : side - 4;
let dir = ['u', 'l', 'd', 'r'][side];
setCur(touch);
return dir;
  } else {
return null;
  }
}
//Функция создает экземпляр игры
function createGame(props) {
  setFrame('game');
  game = new Game(props).init();
  activateListeners();
}
// Функция закрывает текующий экземпляр игры
function closeGame() {
  game = null;
  setFrame('lobby');
  deactivateListeners();
}
// Функция активирует заданный аргументом фрейм
function setFrame(frame) {
  selAll('.frame').forEach(frame => remCls(frame, 'show'));
  return addCls(sel(`.${frame}`), 'show');
}
// Функция включает обработчики
function activateListeners() {
  window.ontouchstart = e => {
if (e.touches.length != 1) {
  clearCur();
} else {
  setCur(e.touches[0]);
}
  };
  window.ontouchmove = e => {
if (e.touches.length != 1) {
  return clearCur();
}
let dir = dirCur(e.touches[0]);
if (dir) {
  game.swap(dir);
}
  };
  window.ontouchend = e => clearCur();
  window.ontouchcancel = e => clearCur();
  window.onkeydown = e => {
[
  ['up', ['ArrowUp', 'KeyW', 'KeyK']],
  ['down', ['ArrowDown', 'KeyS', 'KeyJ']],
  ['left', ['ArrowLeft', 'KeyA', 'KeyH']],
  ['right', ['ArrowRight', 'KeyD', 'KeyL']],
  ['undo', ['Backspace', 'KeyU', 'KeyZ']],
  ['redo', ['Enter', 'KeyR', 'Period']],
].map(([fn, keys]) => {
  if (keys.includes(e.code) && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
game[fn]();
stop(e);
  }
});
  };
  window.onresize = e => {
game.reposition();
  };
  window.onwheel = e => {
stop(e);
  };
}
// Функция выключет обработчики
function deactivateListeners() {
  // удаляем обработчики
  ['keydown', 'touchend', 'touchcancel', 'touchmove', 'touchstart', 'resize', 'wheel'].map(
evt => (window[`on${evt}`] = null)
  );
}
// Функция пересоздает grid
function regrid(size) {
  // Удаляем старые ячейки
  selAll(grid, 'div').forEach(cell => cell.remove());
  // Удаляем старые тайлы
  selAll(layer, 'div').forEach(tile => tile.remove());
  // Добавляем новые ячейки
  for (let i = 0; i < size ** 2; i++) create({ tag: 'div', tgt: grid });
  // Шаблоны grid
  assign(grid.style, {
gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${size} ,1fr)`,
gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${size} ,1fr)`,
  });
  // Динамические стили для тайлов
  dynamic.innerHTML =
Object.entries(COLOR_SCHEMA)
  .map(
([dib, color]) =>
  `#layer .tile[val="${+dib + 1}"]{background: #${color};}
  #layer .tile[val="${+dib + 1}"]::before{
content:"${+dib + 1}";
  }`
  )
  .join('\n') +
`#layer .tile {
font-size: calc(80vmin / ${size * 1.2});
line-height: calc(80vim / ${size * 1.2});
  }`;
}
class Game {
  // размер
  size;
  // сложность
  adv;
  // массив значений
  raw;
  // стек отмен
  stackUndo = [];
  // стек повторов
  stackRedo = [];
  // очки
  _score = 0;
  // флаг начала
  started = false;
  constructor(props) {
assign(this, props);
  }
  // Инициализация
  init() {
if (!this.size) this.size = 4;
if (!this.adv) this.adv = round(this.size * );
if (!this.raw) this.raw = new Array(this.size ** 2).fill(0);
regrid(this.size);
if (!this.started) {
  this.started = true;
  this.addition().addition();
} else {
  this.recreate();
}
this.score = this.score;
return this;
  }
  // Дополнение
  addition() {
// считаем пыстые ячейки
let freeCells = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.size ** 2; i++) {
  if (!this.raw[i]) {
freeCells.push(i);
  }
}
// выбираем рандломную
let pos = freeCells[~~(freeCells.length * random())];
// рандомное значение
let value = 1 + ~~((this.size - 2) * random());
//
let [x, y] = [pos % this.size, ~~(pos / this.size)];
this.raw[pos] = value;
this.createTile(x, y, value, 'addition');
return this;
  }
  // Сделать ход
  swap(dir) {
const [property, method] = {
  u: ['cols', 'backward'],
  d: ['cols', 'forward'],
  r: ['rows', 'forward'],
  l: ['rows', 'backward'],
}[dir];
let lines = this[property];
let newLines = [];
let changes = 0;
// Вызываем метод сдвига
for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
  let line = lines[i];
  let result = this[method](line);
  let { moves, mixes, newLine } = result;
  for (let j = 0; j < moves.length; j++) {
let [from, to] = moves[j];
let [xFrom, yFrom, xTo, yTo] = property == 'cols' ? [i, from, i, to] : [from, i, to, i];
let tile = this.getTile(xFrom, yFrom);
assign(tile.style, this.getRect(xTo, yTo));
attr(tile, 'x', xTo);
attr(tile, 'y', yTo);
  }
  // вызываем метод мутирования
  for (let j = 0; j < mixes.length; j++) {
let [x, y] = property == 'cols' ? [i, mixes[j]] : [mixes[j], i];
let value = newLine[mixes[j]];
this.score += value;
// Удаляем старые тайлы
this.getTile(x, y).remove();
this.getTile(x, y).remove();
// создаем новые тайлы
this.createTile(x, y, value, 'mix');
  }
  changes += mixes.length + moves.length;
  newLines.push(newLine);
}
// Если что-то поменялось
if (changes) {
  // Сохраняем старые значения
  this.stackUndo.push([arr2str(this.raw), this._score]);
  this.stackRedo.splice(0, this.stackRedo.length);
  // Применяем значения
  this[property] = newLines;
  // Добавляем рандомный тайл
  this.addition();
  // Чекнем на вымгрыш или проигрыш
  this.check();
  // На всякий перепозиционируем тайлы
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
this.reposition();
  });
}
  }
  // биндинги сторон
  up() {
this.swap('u');
  }
  down() {
this.swap('d');
  }
  left() {
this.swap('l');
  }
  right() {
this.swap('r');
  }
  // отменить
  undo() {
// если стек пуст
if (!this.stackUndo.length) {
  return;
}
this.stackRedo.push([arr2str(this.raw), this.score]);
let [raw, score] = this.stackUndo.pop();
this.score = score;
this.raw = str2arr(raw);
this.recreate();
  }
  // повторить
  redo() {
// если стек пуст
if (!this.stackRedo.length) {
  return;
}
this.stackUndo.push([arr2str(this.raw), this.score]);
let [raw, score] = this.stackRedo.pop();
this.score = score;
this.raw = str2arr(raw);
this.recreate();
  }
  // Проверка на выигрыш или проигрыш
  check() {
if (this.raw.find(item => item == this.adv)) {
  return setFrame('success');
}
if (!this.raw.includes(0)) {
  for (let y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
for (let x = 0; x < this.size - 1; x++) {
  if (this.raw[y * this.size + x] == this.raw[y * this.size + x + 1]) {
return;
  }
}
  }
  for (let x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
for (let y = 0; y < this.size - 1; y++) {
  if (this.raw[y * this.size + x] == this.raw[(y + 1) * this.size + x]) {
return;
  }
}
  }
  return setFrame('failure');
}
  }
  // сдвигаем назад
  backward(line) {
let moves = [];
let mixes = [];
let skip = [];
let pos = -1;
let lastValue = null;
let lastIndex = null;
let newLine = [];
for (let i = 0, l = line.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (line[i] == 0) {
skip.push(i);
  } else if (lastIndex != null && lastValue != null && line[i] == lastValue) {
moves.push([i, lastIndex]);
mixes.push(lastIndex);
newLine[lastIndex]++;
lastIndex = null;
lastValue = null;
  } else {
lastIndex = newLine.length;
newLine.push(line[i]);
lastValue = line[i];
// }
if (++pos != i) {
  moves.push([i, pos]);
}
  }
}
let endian = this.size - newLine.length;
newLine.splice(newLine.length, 0, ...new Array(endian).fill(0));
return { moves, mixes, newLine };
  }
  // сдвигаем линию вперед
  forward(line) {
let moves = [];
let mixes = [];
let skip = [];
let pos = this.size;
let lastValue = null;
let lastIndex = null;
let newLine = new Array(this.size).fill(0);
for (let i = line.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (line[i] == 0) {
skip.push(i);
  } else if (lastIndex != null && lastValue != null && line[i] == lastValue) {
moves.push([i, lastIndex]);
mixes.push(lastIndex);
newLine[lastIndex]++;
lastIndex = null;
lastValue = null;
  } else {
lastIndex = --pos;
newLine[pos] = line[i];
lastValue = line[i];
if (pos != i) {
  moves.push([i, pos]);
}
  }
}
return { moves, mixes, newLine };
  }
  // перепозиционирование тайлов
  reposition() {
// получаем все тайлы
let tiles = selAll(layer, '.tile');
for (let tile of tiles) {
  let [x, y] = [+attr(tile, 'x'), +attr(tile, 'y')];
  // циклично каждому устанавливаем позицию в соответствии с коордтнатами
  assign(tile.style, this.getRect(x, y));
}
  }
  // пересоздать тайлы
  recreate() {
// удаляем все тайлы
selAll(layer, 'div').forEach(tile => tile.remove());
// создаем тайлы
for (let [pos, dib] of this.raw.entries()) {
  if (!dib) continue;
  let [x, y] = [pos % this.size, ~~(pos / this.size)];
  this.createTile(x, y, dib);
}
  }
  // создать тайл
  createTile(x, y, val, anim) {
let rect = this.getRect(x, y);
let tile = create({
  cls: 'tile',
  atr: { x, y, val },
  css: this.getRect(x, y),
  tgt: layer,
});
if (anim) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
if (anim) {
  tile.classList.add(anim);
}
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  tile.classList.add('transition');
  if (anim) {
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  tile.classList.remove(anim);
});
  }
});
  });
}
return tile;
  }
  // Найти тайл
  getTile(x, y) {
return sel(layer, `div[x="${x}"][y="${y}"]`);
  }
  // Найти область ячейки
  getRect(x, y) {
const rect = sel(grid, `div:nth-child(${this.size * y + x + 1})`).getBoundingClientRect();
return fromEntries(['left', 'top', 'width', 'height'].map(prop => [prop, rect[prop] + 'px']));
  }
  // Свойство возвращает массив столбцов
  get cols() {
const cols = [];
for (let ci = 0, cn = this.size; ci < cn; ci++) {
  let col = [];
  for (let ri = 0, rn = this.size; ri < rn; ri++) {
col.push(this.raw[ri * cn + ci]);
  }
  cols.push(col);
}
return cols;
  }
  // Свойство записывает массив столбцов
  set cols(v) {
for (let ci = 0, cn = this.size; ci < cn; ci++) {
  for (let ri = 0, rn = this.size; ri < rn; ri++) {
this.raw[ri * cn + ci] = v[ci][ri];
  }
}
  }
  // Свойство возвращает массив строк
  get rows() {
const rows = [];
for (let ri = 0, rn = this.size; ri < rn; ri++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let ci = 0, cn = this.size; ci < cn; ci++) {
row.push(this.raw[ri * cn + ci]);
  }
  rows.push(row);
}
return rows;
  }
  // Свойство записывает массив строк
  set rows(v) {
for (let ri = 0, rn = this.size; ri < rn; ri++) {
  for (let ci = 0, cn = this.size; ci < cn; ci++) {
this.raw[ri * cn + ci] = v[ri][ci];
  }
}
  }
  // Свойство возвращает количество очков
  get score() {
return this._score;
  }
  // Свойство устанавливает количество очков
  set score(v) {
selAll('.score').forEach(el => (attr(el, 'text', v).innerHTML = v));
this._score = v;
  }
  // Сериализация игры
  serialize() {
return fromEntries(
  ['size', 'adv', 'raw', 'score', 'started', 'stackUndo', 'stackRedo'].map(prop => [prop, this[prop]])
);
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.frame {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.frame {
  display: none;
}
.show,
.lobby.show,
.new-game,
.panel {
  display: flex;
}
.anim {
  transition: all 100ms;
}
.lobby,
.memo,
.game {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.meta,
.new-game {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.note,
.kbd {
  width: 25rem;
}
.note::before,
.kbd::before {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: block;
}
.note::before {
  content: '⚠';
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.kbd::before {
  content: '⌨';
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}
.meta,
.note,
.kbd {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
table tr th {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
table tr td span {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  border: 1px solid #3339;
  text-align: center;
  background: #8080802b;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4449;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: #000 0px -1px 0px 0px inset;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  forced-color-adjust: none;
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
  -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
h3,
.score,
#layer div {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}
h3,
.score {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
#grid {
  background: #888;
  display: grid;
}
#layer,
#grid {
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  width: calc(100vw - 2rem);
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  max-width: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  max-height: calc(100vw - 2rem);
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  padding: 1vmin;
  gap: 1vmin;
}
#layer div {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
#layer div,
#grid div {
  border-radius: 0.5vmin;
}
#grid div {
  background: #fff;
}
h3,
.failure .score,
.success .score {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fffa;
}
h3 {
  top: 45vh;
}
.failed .score,
.success .score {
  top: 55vh;
}
.layer div {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.2rem #ff0, 0 0 0.4rem #fff;
}
.layer > .tile {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.layer > .tile.addition {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.layer > .tile.mixed {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 0;
}
.transition {
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.exit {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #f00; */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.exit:hover {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #f00;
  top: -2px;
}
.exit:active {
  border: 2px solid #fffc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem #f00;
  top: 2px;
}
.exit::before {
  /* ✖× */
  content: '×';
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button.ok {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  height: calc(100vh - 3rem - 3rem - 3rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  width: calc(100vw - 2rem);
}
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: top;
  width: 100vw;
}
.game .score {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3rem;
  right: 1rem;
  color: #0008;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
button p {
  float: right;
  /* clear: right; */
  margin: 0.8rem 0 0 0.3rem;
}

.undo::before,
.redo::before,
.import::before,
.export::before {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.undo::before {
  content: '◀';
}
.redo::before {
  content: '▶';
}
.export::before {
  content: '';
}
.import::before {
  content: '';
}
.memo[mode='import'] header p::before {
  content: 'Вставте содержимое файла в это поле и нажмите ОК:';
}
.memo[mode='export'] header p::before {
  content: 'Сохраните содержимое файла из этого поля';
}

.memo p {
  margin: 2rem 0 0 1rem;
}
.panel {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

:root {
  --f-size: 15;
  --f-unit: 1vmin;
  --f: calc(var(--f-size) * var(--f-unit));
  --bg: #222;
}
.failure.frame,
.success.frame {
  background: var(--bg);
}
.failure.frame .score,
.failure.frame h3 {
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 0.75;
  margin: auto;
  color: #1af0dc;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleX(var(--scale, 1));
  animation: glitch-p 11s infinite alternate;
  font-size: 6vmin;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.failure.frame .loose {
  top: 45vh;
}
.failure.frame .score {
  top: 55vh;
}
.failure.frame > *::before,
.failure.frame > *::after {
  --top: 0;
  --left: 0;
  --v-height: 30%;
  --n-tenth: calc(var(--f-size) * 0.1 * var(--top));
  --t-cut: calc(var(--n-tenth) / var(--f-size) * 100%);
  --b-cut: calc(var(--t-cut) + var(--v-height));
  content: attr(text);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--left) * 100%));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 transparent);
  text-shadow: calc(var(--left) * -3em) 0 0.02em lime, calc(var(--left) * -6em) 0 0.02em #ff00e1;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  clip-path: polygon(0% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--b-cut), 0% var(--b-cut));
}
.failure.frame > *::before {
  animation: glitch-b 1.7s infinite alternate-reverse;
}
.failure.frame > *::after {
  animation: glitch-a 3.1s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes glitch-p {
  17% {
--scale: 0.87;
  }
  31% {
--scale: 1.1;
  }
  37% {
--scale: 1.3;
  }
  47% {
--scale: 0.91;
  }
  87% {
--scale: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes glitch-a {
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
--top: 0;
--left: 0;
  }
  0% {
--v-height: 15%;
  }
  20% {
--left: 0.005;
  }
  40% {
--left: 0.01;
--v-height: 20%;
--top: 3;
  }
  60% {
--left: 0.03;
--v-height: 25%;
--top: 6;
  }
  80% {
--left: 0.07;
--v-height: 5%;
--top: 8;
  }
  100% {
--left: 0.083;
--v-height: 30%;
--top: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes glitch-b {
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
--top: 0;
--left: 0;
  }
  0% {
--v-height: 15%;
--top: 10;
  }
  20% {
--left: -0.005;
  }
  40% {
--left: -0.01;
--v-height: 17%;
--top: 3;
  }
  60% {
--left: -0.03;
--v-height: 35%;
--top: 6;
  }
  80% {
--left: -0.07;
--v-height: 5%;
--top: 8;
  }
  100% {
--left: -0.083;
--v-height: 30%;
--top: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes mixed {
  0% {
transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<style id="dynamic"></style>
<div class="frame lobby show">
<div class="meta">
  <div class="note">
<p>
  Игра отличается от оригинала!<br />Длинные числа заменены на степени двоек.<br />Например,
  <tt>2 + 2 => 3</tt> и <tt>3 + 3 => 4</tt>.<br />Управление с тачскрина не требует<br />отрыва пальца от
  экрана.<br />Чувствительность сенсора завышена.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kbd">
<table></table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="new-game">
  <button class="import">
<p>Import</p>
  </button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="frame game">
<header>
  <p></p>
  <button class="exit"></button>
</header>
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="export"><p>Export</p></button>
  <button class="undo"><p>Undo</p></button>
  <button class="redo"><p>Redo</p></button>
</div>
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="layer"></div>
<style></style>
</div>

<div class="frame success">
<header>
  <p></p>
  <button class="exit"></button>
</header>
<h3 text="YOU WIN">YOU WIN</h3>
<div class="score"></div>
</div>

<div class="frame failure">
<header>
  <p></p>
  <button class="exit"></button>
</header>
<h3 text="GAME OVER">GAME OVER</h3>
<div class="score"></div>
</div>

<div class="frame memo">
<header>
  <p class="message"></p>
  <button class="exit"></button>
</header>
<textarea></textarea>
<button class="ok">OK</button>
</div>
```